# How many bytes does char defined in a structure take?

Tags: c, data-structures

When I define a character type in a structure, it seems to take more than 1 byte; in fact it seems to take 4 bytes.

Below is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct book{
        char name;
        float price;
        int pages;
    };
    struct book b1={'B',130.00,550};
    printf("\nAddress of structure:%u",&b1);
    printf("\nAddress of character name:%u",&b1.name);
    printf("\nAddress of float price:%u",&b1.price);
    printf("\nAddress of integer pages:%u",&b1.pages);
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above program, I get the output below:

```
    Address of structure:557762432
    Address of character name:557762432
    Address of float price:557762436
    Address of integer pages:557762440
```

Why is it that I see the difference of 4 bytes between address of variable "name" and variable "price"?

The system on which this program is being run is x86_64 bit arch running Fedora-14.

Comment: The compiler is packing the structure so the data members are correctly aligned and the program can run fast. With bad alignment some chips(ARM) just fail on you, others (x86) just run slower.

Comment: In 64 bit machine memory word is created of 64 bit as it was 32bit for 32 bit address
x86_64

Comment: @RashmiKantShrivastwa  Thanks for your replies, Will read more about padding

Answer (score 12):

The C standard allows implementations to add additional padding bits to structures so as to access the structure faster by making it aligned to byte boundaries as required by that implementation.

This is known as **[Structure Padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding)**.

Given the above the size of a structure may not be the same as the sum of the sizes of the individual members. You should always use `sizeof` to determine the size of structure.

Also, the above mentioned is the reason that you do not see the structures members placed at memory addresses you expect them to be at.

Answer (score 3):

You are running into alignment rules.  This is a very compiler- and system-specific thing, but by default (that is, unless you specify otherwise using compiler flags or special alignment requests in the code) GCC on x64 Linux aligns each field of a struct on a multiple of its size.  So, a one-character byte has nothing in particular to worry about for alignment.  However, an int or float is always placed on a 4-byte boundary, and a double is always placed on an 8-byte boundary.  That's what you are seeing here.

As Ethan notes above in the comments, some processors won't even access memory objects that aren't aligned a certain way, and Intel processors will access memory much more slowly if it isn't aligned.

Comment: for your replies, Now i understood why i am seeing this behaviour. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Strictly, the `char` always occupies one byte, but it may be followed by 0 or more bytes padding.  How much padding depends on the compiler, and on the CPU, and on the alignment of the type following the `char` in a structure, and any packing pragmas that are in effect.  If an N-byte type must be N-byte aligned, as on SPARC, for example, then:

```
struct s16 { char c; double d; };
struct s8  { char c; long l;   };
struct s4  { char c; short s;  };
struct s2  { char c; char b;   };
```

The solitary `char` is followed by 7, 3, 1 and 0 bytes in the structures above on a SPARC machine, and also on an x86_64 machine.

Answer (score 0):

A "char" in C typically takes exactly 8 bits (one byte).

However, a char in a struct is "aligned" on a word, dword or even quadword boundary:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

There are compiler directives available to force alignment to 4, 2 or 1 byte (which circumvents this behavior).

For example, in Visual C++, you can say "#pragma pack(1)".